# "asciifolding" with tokenizer "pattern" in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ascii, tokenize, elasticsearch-analyzers

can anyone tell me why "asciifolding" doesn't work on the "pattern" tokenizer in my mapping below?

I need to use the "pattern" tokenizer but I also need to not differentiate words with an accent or without an accent function that "asciifolding" does.

I need "televisão" to be equal to "televisao" but "asciifolding" is not working on my "analyzer_customizado" which has "asciifolding" and tokenizer "pattern"

```
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "5",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "stemmer_plural_portugues": {
            "name": "minimal_portuguese",
            "stopwords" : ["http", "https", "ftp", "www"],
            "type": "stemmer"
          },
          
          
            "synonym_filter": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "lenient": true,
            "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt",
            "updateable" : true

          },
          
       
          "shingle_filter": {
            "type": "shingle",
            "min_shingle_size": 2,
            "max_shingle_size": 3
          }

        },
        
        "analyzer": {
          "analyzer_customizado": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "stemmer_plural_portugues",
              "asciifolding",
              "synonym_filter",
              "shingle_filter"
              
            ],
            "tokenizer": "pattern"
          }
        }

      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
      "properties": {

        "id": {
         "type": "long"
        },
         "data": {
          "type": "date"
        },
         "quebrado": {
          "type": "byte"
          
        },
         "pgrk": {
           "type":  "integer" 
        },
         "url_length": {
           "type":  "integer" 
        },
        "titulo": {
          "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "descricao": {
        "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "url": {
          "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "ignore_above": 256,
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Could someone show me how to fix my mapping for "asciifolding" to work in my "analyzer_customizado" that has the tokenizer "pattern"

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the default `pattern` analyzer which as mentioned in the [official doc of pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html)

> The default pattern is \W+, which splits text whenever it encounters
> non-word characters.

You can test this yourself, using the analyzer API, **which generates two tokens for `televisão` as it considers `ã` non-word char.**

```
{
    "tokenizer": "pattern",
    "text": "televisão"
}

{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "televis",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 7,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "o",
            "start_offset": 8,
            "end_offset": 9,
            "type": "word",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Solution:- Unfortunately there is no `ASCIIfolding char filter` which would have converted it to proper ASCII characters to prevent it being broken into different token in your pattern tokenizer. You can refer [this discuss post](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/asciifolding-character-filter/21716/3) which talks about this and suggests using a custom plugin for it.

**Edit** As @Val suggested in the comment, you can also use the [mapping char filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) and define your own character map which will be converted into the first phase to analysis ie char filter.

Comment: Well, he can certainly define his own [mapping character filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-mapping-charfilter.html) in order to do the asciifolding himself prior to the tokenization phase.

Comment: I don't use ElasticSearch but was curious; it looks like the tokenizer accepts flags, which could include [UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS). With that flag, references make me [think](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html) the regexp `\PL` would split on non-letters (so wouldn't split on ã, though would on 1 or '). The [pattern tokenizer docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) mentioned in the post are important here.

Comment: @Val I thought of telling `mapping char filter` but again I don't know how much char she/he wants to convert so thought of giving the link of plugin but yeah that's also one option and will add now

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja I added the mapping char filter as I show the example of my mapping, but it gives an error and does not create the index

Comment: @Val I added the mapping char filter as I show the example of my mapping, but it gives an error and does not create the index